# Unity Framework memory concern

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, unity-container

I am using Microsoft.Practices.Unity framework 1.2 and I can see the memory usage dramatically increasing over time. I've been watching the Garbage Collector heap sizes for Gen 0, 1 and 2 and Objects seems to be continuously promoted to Gen 2 where they stay and get older and older without been claimed by the GC.

Is there some tuning I could do for avoiding this excessive memory consumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know it's due to unity framework? It's possible your injected instances are not being disposed properly. I suggest RedGate Memory Profiler as it will tell you exactly what is not being collected. Memory leaks are a PITA and i've been dealing with them for the last 2 weeks.

Event handlers are usually the cause of these types of issues. Make sure you manually remove all event handlers.

I've found that the GC is not as great at cleaning things up as you might have thought.

Comment: You are right. It seems it isn't a Unity problem. As a matter of fact I am going to do more test to confirm that this behavior is common to all other .NET applications. Gen 2 objects are rarely claimed by the GC. Thanks for your response.

Comment: We recently discovered a memory leak in the entity framework (entity connections weren't releasing object contexts), are you using EF4?

Comment: heh, glad I stopped using EF. Good find!

Answer (score 0):

If objects are migrating to Gen 2, that means they're still live.  Make sure your classes implement `IDisposable` and that they invoke `Dispose()` on any references they contain.  One way to do this automatically (if you're using C#) is to wrap references in a `using` block.  The references will automatically be disposed of at the end of the block.

Comment: You should implement the IDisposable pattern to clean up any event handlers, Non disposed referenced to disposable objects and clean up unmanaged resources. Using will ONLY make sure the .Dispose() is called on a disposable object, it won't clean up any referenced for you. If you don't manually call Dispose() then the GC will end up doing it by calling the finalizer (if you use Disposable pattern) and thus your objects will still be GCed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am going to try Dispose() in a couple of scenarios. Specifically when leading with huge object graphs that I can ensure are not needed. Even though this goes against what I was once promised: "developers shouldn't deal with memory management". At the end we need to.